# How do i search all columns of kendo grid at the same time?

Tags: search, kendo-ui, filtering, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have tried what this person has done, and it works flawlessly, thank you for this post:

[Search All Columns in KendoUI Grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13938101/search-all-columns-in-kendoui-grid)

however, the problems I am having now is that when you try to search more than one column at a time, as soon as you space to a new word it no longer works as well.

how do I tell it to ignore the spaces and keep searching contains?

so if you search "Verizon LTE" when I search by itself, "Verizon" or "LTE" it works to search like it should, but when they're together, it returns zero results, instead of including both items.

this is my current search, and is the same style as the link above

```
$(document).ready(function () {



//change event
$("#search").keyup(function () {
    var val = $('#search').val();
    $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.filter({
        logic: "or",
        filters: [
            {
                field: "ServiceProviderName",
                operator: "contains",
                value: val
            },
            {
                field: "ManufacturerName",
                operator: "contains",
                value: val
            },
            {
                field: "ModelNumber",
                operator: "contains",
                value: val
            },
            {
                field: "ModelName",
                operator: "contains",
                value: val
            },
            {
                field: "Technology",
                operator: "contains",
                value: val
            },
            {
                field: "OSTypeName",
                operator: "contains",
                value: val
            }
        ]
    });


});
});
```

is this a limitation of Kendo grid filtering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you filter, by default KendoUI is trying to match the entire phrase that you type. So if you put in "Verizon" it will match anything that contains "Verizon". If you put in "LTE" it will match anything that contains "LTE". However, when you put in "Verizon LTE" it will match anything containing "Verizon LTE", whereas it seems like you want it to match "Verizon", "LTE", and "Verizon LTE" (which will happen anyway when it matches on the first two.

In order for this type of filtering to happen, you will need to pre-process `val` in your filtering function in order to create an array of search terms, using space as the token splitter, and then perform your filter on each member of the array and return the aggregate result.

So, in order to split your search term up by spaces:

`var val = $("#search").val().split(" ");`

This will make val an array rather than a literal value, so you'll need to generate your filter array based on each value in this array. There are a number of ways you could do it, but here's one approach:

```
filters: getFieldFilter("ServiceProviderName", "contains", val)
.concat(getFieldFilter("ManufacturerName", "contains", val))
.concat(...);
```

...where getFieldFilter might look like this:

```
function getFieldFilter(field, operator, values) {
   var ret = [];
   for(var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
      ret.push(
          {
             field: field,
             operator: operator,
             value: values[i]
          });
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I was just trying the .Split(" ") and that did some wacky searching things, and returned all the results still.  I"m going to try this and see.  This is off topic, but I've never seen a .push before, can you give a quick explanation of what that does/is?

Comment: `Array.prototype.push()` appends an element to the end of an array and returns the new array's length. Mozilla doc: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

Comment: this doesn't exactly work like I want it to, I forgot to mention that I also want it to continue searching on the searched results...so if Verizon brings back 112 rows, if I add another field, I want to filter on the already filtered fields. is that possible without doing a server search?  Otherwise i'll just have a search field that posts a server search and return all original data each time

Comment: However, this works exactly as I originally posted, thank you for the answer!

Comment: Probably `$("#search").val().trim().split(/[\s]+/)` would be a better way to split the search terms.